# Click and swap data using a javascript callback handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
var tempreture = document.getElementById("temp")

var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();



    requestWeather.open('GET', 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=-31&lon=150');
    requestWeather.onload = function () {
        var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
        console.log(weatherData);
        getTemp(weatherData);
    };    requestWeather.send();

    function getTemp(data) {
        var tempString = "";
        var temp = data.main.temp;
        tempString += "<p class='weather'>" + temp + '&#x2103;' + "</p>";
        tempreture.innerHTML = tempString;

        tempreture.addEventListener("click", function( ) {
        var ftemp = "<p class='weather'>" + changeTemp(temp) + '° F' + "</p>";
        tempreture.innerHTML = ftemp;
        },false);
    }


    function changeTemp(temp){
        var tp = temp * 1.8 + 32;
        var cel =Math.round(tp);

        return cel;
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  id="temp" onclick="getTemp()"></a>
```

**How do I use the `click` callback handler to swap text from a different string**

I want to switch between Fahrenheit and Celsius when a user clicks an element.

This is what I have done so far:

```
   function getTemp(data) {
    var tempString = "";
    var temp = data.main.temp;
    tempreture.addEventListener("click", function( ) {

        tempString += "<p class='weather'>" + temp + '&#x2103;' + "</p>";
    },false)
    tempString += "<p class='weather'>" + changeTemp(temp) + '° F' + "</p>";


    tempreture.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", tempString);

}


function changeTemp(temp){
    var tp = (temp - 32) * 5/9;
    var cel =Math.round(tp);

    return cel;
};
```

I have only tried this using pure javascript. It would be great if someone can give me a hint as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
var temp = data.main.temp;
```

The temp is where I got the data from and is passed down to the HTML. I have done the conversion, but I don't know how to pass it back from the conversion function.

**ADD** the temperature data are come from

```
  var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();


    requestWeather.open('GET', 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + data.lat + '&lon=' + data.lon);


        requestWeather.onload = function () {
            var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
            console.log(weatherData);
            getTemp(weatherData);
    }
```

**Edit** I had tried the click function, now. however, I found same issues with the return back to old value after the click.

Comment: We might need to see more of your code. For example, it doesn't look as though `tempreture` is defined anywhere.

Comment: Also, just so you're aware `changeTemp()` _only_ provides the conversion from F -> C (not the other way around), so once you write to the DOM, you're likely going to have issues, since it's now in C and when the user clicks, it will call `changeTemp()` again, but this function will not convert back to F.

Comment: it's fetch from API , and i was thinking that it can be pass it from the JSON data

Comment: So what should happen when you click on the element twice?

Comment: it should swap between the temp and changeTemp(temp)

Comment: @ jwir3  @ Matus  I edit my code into snippet

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/6bgxofty/2/.

Comment: nope ...t_t ....

Comment: Are you trying to go Fahrenheit to Celsius? It logs that in the console now. Or did you want it to toggle between the 2? Oh wait no you need Fahrenheit.

Comment: yah man , i wanna switch between temp and changeTemp(temp) [C and F]

Comment: Ok so here if you load it or click the a tag it seems to be going to C to F: https://jsfiddle.net/6bgxofty/5/. You can even test it by hardcoding in a C number like 6C and it will give you 43F. If this isn't it then sorry dude. You can also see the C and F temp in the console. But this doesn't toggle right now between the both. Just goes C to F.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149856/discussion-between-fenici-and-daniel-d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you validate the data that the API returns.

```js
var tempreture = document.getElementById("temp")

var requestWeather = new XMLHttpRequest();

// global cache
var currentTemp, 
    currentUnit;


requestWeather.open('GET', 'https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=-31&lon=150');
requestWeather.onload = function() {
    var weatherData = JSON.parse(requestWeather.responseText);
    console.log(weatherData);
    getTemp(weatherData);
};
requestWeather.send();

function getTemp(data) {
    currentTemp = typeof data === 'object' ? data.main.temp : null; // save new value in global cache

    currentUnit = 'celcius';

    tempreture.innerHTML = currentTemp + '&#x2103;';
}

tempreture.addEventListener("click", function() {
    tempreture.innerHTML = changeTemp();
}, false);


function changeTemp() {
    if(currentUnit === 'celcius') {
        var tp = currentTemp * 1.8 + 32;
        var fh = Math.round(tp);

        currentUnit = 'fahrenheit';

        return fh + '° F';
    } else {
        currentUnit = 'celcius';
        return currentTemp + '&#x2103;';
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="temp" class='weather'></span>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I was thinking and searching for the conditional statement I couldn't find any of that.